# excel vba inputbox

Tags: email, excel, vba

I am have the following code for excel vba that will email a range of addresses in my sheet. Howeve, I am looking to maybe use an inputbox to determine what the range is that I would like to email. The trouble i run into is getting the input to become a value that the function mailid understands. any suggestions?

```
Sub EmailActiveSheetWithOutlook2()

Dim oApp, oMail As Object, _
tWB, cWB As Workbook, _
FileName, FilePath As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Set email id here, it may be a range in case you have email id on your worksheet

 Sheets("Sheet1").Select
 mailId = Range("b4:b5").Value


'Write your email message body here , add more lines using & vbLf _ at the end of each line

Body = "Hello, it appears you have not yet filled out the transportation contact information excel sheet. This sheet was emailed to you, please complete this and send to me  saved as your firstnamelastname.xls at your earliest convience." & vbLf _
& vbLf _
& "Thanks & Regards" & vbLf _
& vbLf _
& "-Ryan " & vbLf _
```

'Sending email through outlook

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
With oMail
    .To = mailid
    .Subject = "Transportation Committee Notice"
    .Body = Body
    '.Attachments.Add tWB.FullName
    .send
End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To replicate the effect of your current code use

```
mailid = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select Range", Type:=8)
```

where `Type:=8` specifies a return type of `Range`.  This returns the `Value` property of the selected range into `mailid`

Alternatively use

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select Range", Type:=8)
mailid = rng.Value
```

`rng` is then set to the selected range, and can be validated before use

Note that you should add error handling to account for, eg user Cancelling the InputBox

Do not set `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before issuing `InputBox` as this will prevent the user interacting with the screen.

As an aside, your code uses `Dim` incorrectly: `Dim`'ing a variable without a `As` clause declares it as `Variant.
eg

```
Dim oApp, oMail As Object
```

actually declares `oApp` as a `Variant`, use

```
Dim oApp As Object, oMail As Object
```

Comment: chris- thank you very much, i am trying to learn vba on the fly as i continue to realize all of its potential. I really do appreciate you pointing out the dim'ing mistake i made!

Comment: chris, i am getting a run-time error 'array lower bound must be zero' any thoughts on why this occurs/a soultion?

Comment: On what line is the error?  If its the `mailid = ` how is `mailid` `Dim`'ed?

Comment: .To = mailid is what the debugger is highlighting, mailid isnt dim'ed as anything, what should it be?

Comment: Since `mailid` is not `Dim`ed it will be a variant.  When a range is assigned to a variant, the variant becomes a 2 dimensional 1 based array (1 to rows, 1 to columns).  You are assigning this to the `.To` property of a item created by `Outlook`.  I don't have outlook installed so can't test it, but the error suggests you need to structure your To list as a 0 based array (and i would guess 1 dimensional)  I suggest you google `Outlook Object Model` to look into the correct format for the To property.